# android application integrating with facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm developing an android that integrated with the facebook. I have a question about these lines of code

```
 Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken()); 
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
```

I'm confused about the use of editor.putstring function

My question the value of TOKEN can be? and from where can i see the token names that can be used in the function putString?
I didn't find information about this issue through the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nada,

The TOKEN is the Facebook Access Token for that user. Storing it in the editor allows you to read it later from the Shared Preferences instead of querying Facebook servers for an access token and going through the login process again. For more context please checkout the [Facebook Android Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) or a tutorial I wrote [here](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your access token to use in login time and access token is used with different url of facebook graph api to fetch detail of facebook account , profile image etc.
To insure you are logged in , it also help ful to application to store in permanent storage. So we have to store in in preferences .